# Fill input field with value based on member's expiration date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website: http://communitychessclub.com/cccr-pairing/account.html and I want the EF (entrance fee) to be $5 for non-members based on the members.Expires YYYY.MM.DD and $3 for regular members. I need to be able to overwrite the EF amount with any single integer that I choose. Can anyone please help with this?

```
<script src="assets/PLAYERS.JS"></script>

<script src="assets/MEMBERS.JSON"></script> 

    var members = [
{"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Expires": "2017.10.05"},
{"Name": "Attaya, James", "Expires": "2018.01.12"},
...  
{"Name": "Wells, Lucas", "Expires": "2016.08.25"},
{"Name": "Worl, David", "Expires": "2018.01.10"}
];
```

HTML:

```
<!-- start player arrival -->
<div class="universal">
<div class = "cucumber"></div><div class = "ui-widget glasnost">
<input type = "text" id = "P01" placeholder="Last, First"  maxlength = "25" class = "automplete-2 text person" autofocus > </div>

<div class="EF">EF $ <input type="text" onblur="findTotalEF()" name = "ef-fee" style="margin-right:1rem; width:1rem;" class="number fee fee_amt" maxlength = "1" size = "1"></div>
<div class="MEM">MEM $ <input type="text" onblur="findTotalMem()" name = "mem-fee"  class="number fee" maxlength = "2" size = "2"></div>
    <div class="EXP">EXP <input type="text" id="X01" name = "expires" class="number fee expDate" maxlength = "12" size = "12" disabled></div></div>


var members = [
{"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Expires": "2017.10.05"},
{"Name": "Attaya, James", "Expires": "2018.01.12"},
...  
{"Name": "Wells, Lucas", "Expires": "2016.08.25"},
{"Name": "Worl, David", "Expires": "2018.01.10"}
];


<script> // Lookup date of expiration


function getExpireDate(ele) {
var i = null;
for (i = 0; members.length > i; i++) {
    if (members[i].Name == ele.value) {
        var exDate = moment(members[i].Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD');
        if (moment().isAfter(exDate)) {
            $(ele).closest('.universal').find('.expDate').css('color', "#FF0000");
        } else {
            $(ele).closest('.universal').find('.expDate').css('color', "#1EDD59");
        }
        return members[i].Expires;

    }
}
return;
}

// Lookup date of expiration
$("#P01").on("blur", function(){$("#X01").val(getExpireDate(this));});
$("#P02").on("blur", function(){$("#X02").val(getExpireDate(this));});
$("#P03").on("blur", function(){$("#X03").val(getExpireDate(this));});
$("#P04").on("blur", function(){$("#X04").val(getExpireDate(this));});
```

Comment: How are you going to understand if someone is a member?I think you have to do it with some server side code!

Comment: The first input field is a lookup to PLAYERS.JS and onblur that name is auto-completed. Then I want to take that new value and look up in MEMBERS.JSON the members.Expires date

Comment: There's no value for `X01` object.Try this:`<input type="text" id="X01" name = "expires" class="number fee expDate hide" maxlength = "12" size = "12" value="VALUE" disabled>`(I mean you have to add `value=` to your text input).

Comment: Also I can see that your JSON response isn't in `<script></script>`.It's amid your html code!

Comment: I edited the code.